# PHP How to EDIT And Delete line in txt file

Tags: php, file, edit

I have one CFG file so i need to edit and delete lines...i have using this code but it does not replace line.

```
/* check if user exists */
$delete = "F: $username $password # { startdate=$today | enddate=$expired | info=$info | dealer=$dealer }";
$out = array();
while (($line = fgets($stream)) !== false) {
     if(trim($line) != $delete) {
        /* user already exists - we can edit it */
        $out[] = $line;
    }
}

/* write file */
$sftp = ssh2_sftp($con);
$stream = fopen("ssh2.sftp://$sftp/myurl/config/txtfile.cfg", 'w+') or die("can't open file");
flock($stream, LOCK_EX);
foreach($out as $line) {
    fwrite($stream, $line);
}
flock($stream, LOCK_UN);
fclose($stream);
```

I have 100 lines in that txt file and i have send this with ajax:

F: lolipop shugar # { startdate=2015-08-04 | enddate=2016-08-04 | info=informations | dealer=current dealer }

so after writing back to txt cfg file it needs to be written 99 lines without line that begins F: lolipop...so that line is deletet (then i can implement edit line...the idea is to delete line with F: knowusername and then insert new one with new data)

I have try this...file is read correctly into array but file is not written back to txt cfg files with changes...i have txt cfg file that is unchanged with 100lines...could someone post solution?

Thanks

Example:

i have in file:

```
F: user010 sdfsdfsdf # { startdate=$today | enddate=$expired | info=$info | dealer=$dealer }
F: huikkd rrrrr # { startdate=$today | enddate=$expired | info=$info | dealer=$dealer }
F: robot56 uxDtpNjf # { startdate=$today | enddate=$expired | info=$info | dealer=$dealer }
```

so i want to find line:

```
F: huikkd rrrrr # { startdate=$today | enddate=$expired | info=$info | dealer=$dealer }
```

and edit it to:

```
F: huikkd changedpassword # { startdate=$today | enddate=$expired | info=$info | dealer=$dealer }
```

and write it back to cfg file..i im saving file on server throught ssh2 connection

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to edit any line of cfg file. Do not remove `\n`. Just edit the text before `\n`. Hope this code will help:

```
<?php
$line=file('text.cfg',FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$line[4]="jhasrd ady"."\n";//This will edit line 4 with text jhasrd ady
$content=implode('',$line);
file_put_contents('text.cfg',$content);
```

Comment: Thanks...but i need to edit whole line..because you see in example that i have these parameters that i need to change: [code]F: $username $password # { startdate=$today | enddate=$expired | info=$info | dealer=$dealer }[/code]

Comment: @user2631534 the code will update whole line number 4

Comment: @user2631534 If you want to pass variable values you can. Since i used double quotes.

Comment: why not? i mean what you actually want to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for helping me...i would like to edit line..example i will give up in question